# Error after having installed BizTalk Adapter Pack

Tags: asp.net, biztalk

During a BizTalk workshop I installed Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack and Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack (x64).

The next day, when I tried to debug an ASP.NET Web Forms site locally, I received a server error:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. The following information may be a subset of the Type/LoaderException information present - inspect with debugger for complete view.
Check assemblies [Microsoft.Adapters.SAP, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35] and/or types [Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.AdapterHelper,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.FileNameHintHelper,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.TimeoutHelper,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.AdapterMessage,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.AdapterBodyWriter,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.CommonAdapter,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.CommonBinding,
Microsoft.Adapters.AdapterUtilities.CommonStandardBindingElement,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredAsyncDelegateData,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredAsyncResultSignalFinishedDelegate,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredAsyncResult,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.ILayeredOutboundChannelHandler,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.ILayeredInboundChannelHandler,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredBindingElement,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredChannelBehaviour,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.StaticContext`1,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredChannelFactory`1,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredChannelFactory`1+OnOpenDelegate,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredChannelFactory`1+OnCloseDelegate,
Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.TChannelPlusUserData`1]. Information from LoaderExceptions property [The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E),
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E),
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)].
```

Has anyone experienced the same error and managed to get rid of it?

The thing is the site I'm trying to debug doesn't use anything connected to BizTalk. It just stopped working so to speak.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

//Marcus

Comment: Check your sites Application Pool if it offers the correct .Net Framework version. Running `aspnet_regiis.exe` from the according version might fix this. Also have an eye on the correct bitness - your site may depend on running in 32-Bit instead of 64-Bit.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, Filburt. I ended up with uninstalling the adapters I didn't need and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the BizTalk installation program and uninstall all unnecessary adapters (both x86 and x64).

In my case I kept the adapter for Microsoft SQL Server while uninstalling the following:
Oracle Database, Oracle E-Business Suite, mySAP Business Suite.